# Delete activity from all Getstream feeds is not working

Tags: php, getstream-io

With getstream.io I thought that by deleting an activity from a feed using its unique ID that activity would be deleted from all the follower feeds and the feeds that received it via "to" paramter. I'm testing this and I can't see it happen (I manage to remove the activity from the "origin" user feed but it remains in the notification feed of the object, that received the activity because I added the "to" when adding the activity).

Comment: Can you email support @ getstream.io about this?

Comment: I did it but I am not getting any answer